# Why would a dll not get created in the obj folder and how can I fix this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

Have a coworker who can't compile his ASP.net MVC 5 solution.  He's getting an error saying the dll in the obj/Debug folder doesn't exist.  Any ideas what the problem may be?

The solution has three projects.  He says he cleans and rebuilds the entire solution and gets an error about the dll being missing.  He says the obj/Debug folder exists, but there are no dll files in it after the clean and rebuild.  It works fine on my machine and another co-worker's.  I don't have access to his machine.  I've found suggestions on how to fix files not getting copied to the bin folder, but not the obj.  I suggested that he check the output folder in the project's build properties and he says he has.  I can't reproduce the problem and can't find anything online like this.  The odd thing to me is that the project being rebuilt is the same one saying it can't find the file (that is, project WFC can't find the WFC.dll file).

[image]

Comment: Try compiling one of the dependencies, and then change the dropdown from `Build + IntelliSense` to `Build Only`. Then post the actual error message that is causing it not to build here. Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 seem to have some issues where it doesn't always show the error that is causing the build to fail unless you change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did he add the project from a WFC template? 
Does the relevant project folder have a reference to the WFC Service? 
In addition, is the VS version 2017? If so, he might need to import 'Connected Services'.

Comment: He got the code directly from a co-worker (solution file, 3 project files, the entire file structure).  First through Subversion and then (when that didn't work) by copying files.  This is VS 2015.  Not sure what Connected Services are or what you mean by WFC Service.  The WFC project is dependent on the other two, but the other two won't even compile separately.  Thanks!